# How to extract the upper triangular matrix w or w/o diagonal in Chapel

Tags: chapel

The best stories start with my matrix `A`.

```
var A: [{1..4,1..4}] real = (
  (4, -30, 60, -35),
  (-30, 300, -675, 420),
  (60, -675, 1620, -1050),
  (-35, 420, -1050, 700)
  );
```

I recall somewhere you can get the upper triangle, but I can't find it in the [Chapel docs](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/1.14/search.html?q=upper&check_keywords=yes&area=default) Can you set it to in/exclude the diagonal?

Comment: Do you want the left upper triangle or right upper triangle?

Comment: By convention, I usually think right upper tri.  I suppose that could be a switch as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `LinearAlgebra` library:

```
use LinearAlgebra;

var A: [{1..4,1..4}] real = (
  (4, -30, 60, -35),
  (-30, 300, -675, 420),
  (60, -675, 1620, -1050),
  (-35, 420, -1050, 700)
  );

var upperTriangle = triu(A);

// Confirm it worked
writeln(isTriu(upperTriangle));
```

Comment: That's what I needed, turns out it was [here](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.html?highlight=upper#LinearAlgebra.triu) but I couldn't remember the name.